# Liberty Profile and MQ version conflict

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

I currently have an environment where I am trying to get a Liberty Profile v8.5.5.9(using Java 7) to utilize a WebSphere MQ v9.0.3(using Java 8).  These two are on the same box, the server.xml is configured correctly, but I'm getting a namespace error when I'm trying to do a direct client connection.

I'm just trying to rule out if there's a problem using these two versions together that would cause a JNDI problem.

Comment: Without the namespace error it isn't really possible to answer the question.

Comment: It was a conflict apparently.  I removed MQ 9 and installed MQ 7.5 and it started working fine.

Comment: Were you using the 1.1 or 2.0 version of the feature?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There apparently is a conflict between the two environments.  Once I removed 9.0.3 and installed 7.5(MQ) it now works.

Comment: Apparently, misconfigured your environment, as it is clearly stated [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q128160_.htm) that MQ v9 is fully supported with Liberty. You also didn't provide exception stacktrace to fully understand your issue. So your answer is just hypothetical and misleading.